# Can't access Nautilus (File) settings/preferences on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: gnome, nautilus, files, 22.04, settings

I'm trying to access Nautilus settings in order to change default list columns (and more generally to explore all available options). The setting pane should look like this :

[image]

But...

1. The "settings" option does not show in the top menu "Files" dropdown :

[image]

2. The "preferences" option in any Files window (through the hamburger menu) leads to settings relative to the window itself, they don't apply to the whole filesystem :

[image]

[image]

3. In GNOME Tweaks, there is no option relative to top menu that could help :

[image]

4. Using [dconf](https://askubuntu.com/a/973259/1609112) didn't help me, as it does'nt handle all Nautilus settings (and using gsettings gets a little too technical to me...).

I went through several topics on AskUbuntu.com :

- [How to open Nautilus (File Manager) preferences?](https://askubuntu.com/q/861333/1609112) clues : suggests to use top menu dropdown (not true anymore, as [explained here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1198688/1609112)) / I'm not using several monitors / Turning all GNOME extensions off doesn't solve the issue (Dash to Panel is not even installed)
- [How to open Nautilus (File Manager) preferences in 13.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/334570/how-to-open-nautilus-file-manager-preferences-in-13-04) : no new clue
- [File manager's preferences Ubuntu 19.10](https://askubuntu.com/q/1198678/1609112) clues : Alt+E doesn't do anything while having a Files window active (looks like it is only working in [Unity or Mate DE's](https://askubuntu.com/a/865124/1609112))
- [Nautilus bhaviour preferences in 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1413013/nautilus-bhaviour-preferences-in-22-04) : could be a related issue but it is not solved

Thank you very much,

Best regards,

K.

PS: I have no experience about this issue on previous releases of Ubuntu or other OS with GNOME, as I'm a Linux newbie and I just started from Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

Comment: I have no clue what you want to change. Your second picture shows you the Nautilus Preferences menu.

Comment: @vanadium : hello, I'm trying to access this pane : https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1RyC.png ( https://askubuntu.com/a/334577/1609112 ). My actual purpose is to change default list columns (but I would also like to explore all available options). I will edit my post in order to be more specific. Thanks !

Comment: I answered your current question, i.e., about opening the preferences, but you will need to ask about your actual purpose in a new question.

Answer (score 1):

> The setting pane should look like this

It shouldn't. Applications change, and how the interface looks is actually decided upon by the developers. Files 40 changed quite a bit.

You demonstrated that you actually *can* access the preferences in Files. The preference pane is now organized the way you see in [your picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5DBI.png). Instead of tabs, there is a single pane with sections. Several options are not anymore exposed, or have been removed, including the behavior when clicking executables, or removing a confirmation before deleting the trash.

Comment: Good answer but I would add a **Note** that Ubuntu Unity could be installed on 22.04 for a different look and feel from GNOME 42 desktop.