# Ho do I enable the Bash Pop Up Window?

Tags: gnome, scripts, click-policy

I want to run a .sh file in the Terminal. Apparently there is a pop up for that:
[image: pop-up window providing launch options for a shell script]

I don't get that pop up when right clicking the .sh file and the way shown [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38661/how-do-i-run-sh-files/1065846#1065846) doesn't work:
If I right click "files", there is nothing like "Select Preferences".

Can someone help me enable that pop up?

What I see when right clicking the "Files" program when it's closed:
[image]

If open this, this is what I see:

[image]

Right clicking on my .sh file looks like this, even after doing this command:

```
chmod +x meinscript.sh
```

[image]

"Run as a Program" doesn't open the terminal that I need.

Comment: See my updated answer.  You need to open the File Manager and then click on the "Files" caption in the top left hand corner.

Comment: The preferences option for files changes in Ubuntu 22, see: [Can't access Nautilus (File) settings/preferences on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1416824/cant-access-nautilus-file-settings-preferences-on-ubuntu-22-04-lts) "....Several options are not anymore exposed, or have been removed, including the behavior when clicking executables,...."

Answer (score -1):

Don't right click on the .sh file...  Right click on the word "Files" in the top left hand corner of the Files Window.  Then select Preferences, etc.

You will have to ensure the .sh file is executable first...

Launch a Terminal window, cd into the directory of the .sh file and run:

```
chmod +x filename.sh
```

That will make it executable by EVERYONE...  You might want to limit it to either User (u), Group (g) or Other (o).

So, for just the user you would run:

```
chmod u+x filename.sh
```

[image: Click on this...]

Right clicking on the above and clicking "Preferences" will load the following:

[image]

NOTE: The above is for Ubuntu 18.04, for 20.04 the same Preferences can be found in the button with the three horizontal lines as shown here:

[image]

Clicking on that and selecting "Preferences" will load the following window:

[image]

Comment: Still don't see "Preferences" only "All Windows, New Windows, Documents, Download, Music, Pictures, Videos, Remove from Favorites and Quit" if the Programm "Files" is open. And if closed: "New WIndows and Remove from Favorites"

Comment: @PhiliBoy Your not clicking on the right part of the window.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQfZu.jpg This is my dektop where can I find that icon?

Comment: @PhiliBoy - Ok your on a different version.  See the three horizontal lines on the right hand side - click on those and go to Preferences.  I'll add it to my answer

Comment: After going to the Prefernces I can't choose betwen the tabs "Views" "Behaviour" etc. I just have one menu: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Guk9n.png. In there there is no such thing as "Executable Text Files". I have Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS I should have probably said that earlier.